# BlueTooth Connect to a embedded device that requires a PIN

Tags: android

I am writing and Android app that would detect and connect to a know embedded device. The issue my side is that it throws exception whenever I am trying to connect:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            try {
            device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Try Connecting to device : " + device.getName(),
                      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               byte[] pin = (byte[]) BluetoothDevice.class.getMethod("convertPinToBytes", String.class).invoke(BluetoothDevice.class, "1234");
                BluetoothDevice.class.getMethod("setPin", byte[].class).invoke(device, pin);
                BlueToothConnect(device);
            }catch(Exception e){}
       }
    }
};
```

And my BlueToothConnect method is :

```
public void BlueToothConnect(BluetoothDevice device){
            if (deviceName.equals(device.getName()))
            {
                 try
                 {

                //mSocket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
                    Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
                 mSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);

                     mSocket.connect();
                    GetConnectionDetails();
                     result = device;
                     blueTooth_On_off = 1;
                 }
                catch(Exception  e){
                    text.setText(getStackTrace(e));
                try{

                    result = null;
                    mSocket.close();
                    blueTooth_On_off = 0;
                }
                catch(IOException e1){
                    result = null;
                    blueTooth_On_off = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

I am getting below exception error:

**java.io.exception:[jsr82] connect: Connection is not created (failed or aborterd)**

I cannot do much on embedded device side either.

Below is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.edazzelsmarthome"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.edazzelsmarthome.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".broadcast.PairingRequest">
            <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_REQUEST" /> 
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_CANCEL" /> 
                </intent-filter>
         </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Do you give <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />

Comment: `final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (intent.getAction().equals(action))` pretty weird condition :/

Comment: Yes I have updated the question with all other details

Comment: Yes, ignore those as I am forcing the code path to traverse there